# Most efficient way to fill a new python pandas column through a custom function that uses two other pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

and thanks for the time.

I am currently in a pursuit of trying to optimize my code as much as possible, and have been getting a little scatterbrained surrounding my idea. I have found a lot of similar threads, but many of the code does not seem to work as well as expected.

I am creating new columns to a database with 100,000's of rows, and am trying to make my code as efficient as possible, within the context of pandas.

Let us say I have a dataframe:

```
df = ...
x,y,z
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

here are a few examples of function types I could use

```
def multFunc(x,y,z): 
    return(x*y*z)

df['a'] = multFunc(df['x'],df['y'],df['z'])
```

in some situations, these functions may pass constants as well

```
df['a'] = multFunc(df['x'],df['y'],20)
```

What is the fastest way computationally to create a new column a, by running multFunc on all of the rows?

```
I have tried so far: 

df['a'] = multFunc(df['x'],df['y'],df['z'])

df['a'] = df[['x','y','z']].apply(lambda x: multFunx(*x),axis = 1)
```

Any help greatly appreciated, or a link to another thread. Thanks!

Comment: What does `multFunc` do precisely? How complicated is it?

Comment: in my use case, I have about 30 functions that are set up as such like multFunc, multFunc is an function that uses multiple arguments creates an output, and at that point I just pass multiple pandas series to return another pandas series, each function that I have is designed to work on a row by row basis. some of these functions involve constants that are passed as well, some don't, some involve 5 arguments, some 2, a lot of variety, but these functions are semi-complicated.

Comment: Okay... are they similar to something you could do as: `df.x * df.y / df.z` instead?

Comment: Let me test that quickly and how fast it is, but based off initial testing, it seems to not make a speed difference compared to the first method.

Comment: Does multFunc return a dataframe or a scalar value?  Does MultFunc accept scalar values or list or pd.Series as parameters?

Comment: so i re-updated my question, but typically it could a combination of scalars and pandas series, but they are designed at the moment to return pandas series if I pass through at least one pandas series, which I always do, but I would be open to trying to set them up another way.